# Is Spock plugin required for grails-2.4.4

Tags: grails, grails-2.4

I am using grails-2.4.4 version of grails.

I want know,Is spock plugin required for grails-2.4.4.?

I want to perform integration testing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to include any dependencies of Spock in Grails 2.4.4, because it is included from the 2.3 version.